# Prove that the union of two normal and separated subspaces is normal

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. $A$ and $B$ are separated sets in $(X,\tau)$, i.e.,$\overline{A}\cap B=A\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$. If the subspaces $(A,\tau\cap A)$ and $(B,\tau\cap B)$ are normal. How can we prove that $(A\cup B,\tau\cap (A\cup B))$ is normal?

**My attempt.** Let $F\cap(A\cup B)$ be a closed set in $(A\cup B,\tau\cap (A\cup B))$ and $V\cap(A\cup B)$ be a open neighbourhood of $F\cap(A\cup B)$ where $F$ is closed in $(X,\tau)$ and $V\in \tau$. We have $F\cap A\subset V\cap A$ and $F\cap B\subset V\cap B$. So there exist $P\in \tau$ and $Q\in\tau$ that satisify $F\cap A\subset P\cap A\subset\overline{P}\cap A\subset V\cap A$ and
$F\cap B\subset Q\cap B\subset\overline{Q}\cap B\subset V\cap B$ by the normality of $(A,\tau\cap A)$ and $(B,\tau\cap B)$. And we can choose $P$ and $Q$ such that $P\cap \overline{B}=Q\cap \overline{A}=\emptyset$. It seems that $(P\cup Q)\cap(A\cup B)$ should satisify $$F\cap(A\cup B)\subset (P\cup Q)\cap(A\cup B)\subset(\overline{P\cup Q})\cap(A\cup B)\subset V\cap(A\cup B)$$
But I failed to show that $(\overline{P\cup Q})\cap(A\cup B)\subset V\cap(A\cup B)$. Because $\overline{P}\cap B$ and $\overline{Q}\cap A$ may not be empty sets.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to math stack exchange. I have spotted a potential error in your attempt, $\overline{P\cap A} \subseteq V\cap A$, not $\overline{P} \cap A \subseteq V\cap A$. I can’t show $(P\cap A) \cup (Q\cap B)$ is open in $A\cup B$. If that set is open in $A\cup B$, then $\overline{(P\cap A) \cup (Q\cap B)}=\overline{(P\cap A)} \cup \overline{(Q\cap B)}\subseteq (V\cap A) \cup ( V\cap B)= V\cap (A\cup B)$ and $F\cap (A\cup B) \subseteq (P\cap A) \cup (Q\cap B)$ holds trivially.

Comment: Perhaps we also have to use(somewhere) separate condition.